# i/o error during create file in vs2013 with Firebird db and iis 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, firebird, iis-10

I'm working on an asp.net project in visual studio 2013 which uses Firebird as the database server. I have no problems with Windows 8 or if I deployed the project on a remote server, but if I work on a PC with Windows 10 and IIS and I tried to debug the project in visual studio, it is not possible to open the connection with the database, I got the error I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "path and name of the database file" Error while trying to open file. 
I think the problem is in the IIS configuration but I can't find out where it is. Surely someone can guide me...

Comment: Please post the relevant code (see [mcve]), make sure to include your full connection string as well and the full exception stacktrace, and be more specific about the location of the file. Common causes of this error include trying to open a database in a location where the user running the Firebird server process doesn't have read/write access, or the database simply not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I moved the database to the app_data folder of the project and the error disappeared